# Upgraded RDS postgres from 11.16 to 14.4, CPU has been stuck at 100% for hours while running the huge aggregate queries

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have upgraded our **AWS RDS Postgres** from  11.16 to 14.4, After that I can see CPU stay around 100% for long hours while running the aggregate Queries.

I'm working with a large database. Most of the main tables have 1 million records. While running these aggregate queries in previous version (11.16) it will give the result without increasing the CPU usage.

Can we use **ANALYZE** command for optimizing the upgraded database?
Is there any impact when we running this command on database?
Any suggestions for resolving this?

Comment: You should contact Amazon's support

Comment: You can compare the execution plans.

Comment: Yes, you can (and should) use ANALYZE after the upgrade. By the way, lakhs is unknown to me

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood.